# SoundManager loading sound from different folder

Tags: objective-c, directory

I've been working around in Objective C and I use SoundManager to load my music/sound, but now I try to load some sound from a different folder (MyXcodeProjectFolder/Soundboard/whatever.mp3/) but the SoundManager always say that the file doesn't exist, do someone have a awesome for me ? I tried alot of way but each time he wasn't able to find it or he was just not playing it at all.

Here some code I wrote:

```
Inside my ViewController.h
[soundLoader playSound:@"~/Soundboard/letitgoremix.mp3"];


Inside the soundLoader (Not mine, just made an object for playing sound faster)

+(void)playSound: (NSString *)song
{
    [SoundManager sharedManager].allowsBackgroundMusic = YES;
    [[SoundManager sharedManager] prepareToPlay];

    if ([SoundManager sharedManager].playingMusic)
    {
        [[SoundManager sharedManager] stopMusic: true];
    }

    [[SoundManager sharedManager] playMusic:song looping:NO];
}
```

For the SoundManager source you can take a look here : https://github.com/nicklockwood/SoundManager

Also it's my first time coding with Xcode and with Objective-c so i'm sorry if my syntax is not correct.

Thanks you for reading and I hope that somebody will help me out to fix my problem.

**EDIT:**

I found the problem, my music folder wasn't added correctly in Xcode which was not making it a correct copy inside the .app.

Comment: You can post the answer as an answer below and accept it as the correct one. That will both increase your reputation and let people know the question has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix my problem I needed to do two things:

1. Set the music folder as a reference and not a group.
2. I use this code to load my sounds/musics inside a folder.

The code: Just change "MusicFileNameHere" and "Folder/Location/here".

```
NSString *music = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MusicFileNameHere" ofType:@"mp3" inDirectory:@"Folder/Location/Here"];
```

Hope that will help people with the same problem as me!